# AES encryption on xcode and decryption nodejs

Tags: xcode, node.js, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a string on xcode using AES and decrypt it back on nodejs.

Although I can encrypt and decrypt it on xcode side, I cannot decrypt it on nodejs.

I log the base64 output of the encryption and copy it to nodejs. Then I try to decrypt it there but it fails with TypeError: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

My nodejs part:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var input = "my secret text";
var passkey = "mykey";
var algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';//['aes-128-cbc', 'aes-128-ecb', 'aes-192-cbc', 'aes-192-ecb', 'aes-256-cbc', 'aes-256-ecb'];
console.log("Tryin ---> " + algorithm);

try{
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, passkey);
    var plain = decipher.update('ozADZS121rHjBVogcx8Tfw==', 'base64', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
    console.log('plain');
    console.log(plain);
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

My xcode part:

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NSData+AES.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {
const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
NSInteger length = [theData length];

static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

NSInteger i;
for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
    NSInteger value = 0;
    NSInteger j;
    for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
        value <<= 8;

        if (j < length) {
            value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
        }
    }

    NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
    output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
    output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
    output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
}

return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

NSData *dataToEnc = [@"my secret text" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encryptedData = [dataToEnc AES256EncryptWithKey:@"mykey"];

NSLog(@"base64: %@",[self base64forData:encryptedData]);


return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

@end
```

NSData+AES.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (AES)

- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;

+ (NSData *)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;
- (id)initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;

- (NSString *)base64Encoding;
- (NSString *)base64EncodingWithLineLength:(NSUInteger)lineLength;

- (BOOL)hasPrefixBytes:(const void *)prefix length:(NSUInteger)length;
- (BOOL)hasSuffixBytes:(const void *)suffix length:(NSUInteger)length;

@end
```

NSData+AES.m

```
#import "NSData+AES.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

static char encodingTable[64] =
{
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
    'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f',
    'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
    'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/'
};

@implementation NSData (AES)

- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key{
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256  ,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted );
    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free( buffer ); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key{

    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted );

    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free( buffer ); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}

#pragma mark -

+ (NSData *)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string
{
    return [[NSData allocWithZone:nil] initWithBase64EncodedString:string];
}

- (id)initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSMutableData *mutableData = nil;

    if( string )
    {
        unsigned long ixtext = 0;
        unsigned long lentext = 0;
        unsigned char ch = 0;
        unsigned char inbuf[4], outbuf[3];
        short i = 0, ixinbuf = 0;
        BOOL flignore = NO;
        BOOL flendtext = NO;
        NSData *base64Data = nil;
        const unsigned char *base64Bytes = nil;

        // Convert the string to ASCII data.
        base64Data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        base64Bytes = [base64Data bytes];
        mutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:base64Data.length];
        lentext = base64Data.length;

        while( YES )
        {
            if( ixtext >= lentext ) break;
            ch = base64Bytes[ixtext++];
            flignore = NO;

            if( ( ch >= 'A' ) && ( ch <= 'Z' ) ) ch = ch - 'A';
            else if( ( ch >= 'a' ) && ( ch <= 'z' ) ) ch = ch - 'a' + 26;
            else if( ( ch >= '0' ) && ( ch <= '9' ) ) ch = ch - '0' + 52;
            else if( ch == '+' ) ch = 62;
            else if( ch == '=' ) flendtext = YES;
            else if( ch == '/' ) ch = 63;
            else flignore = YES;

            if( ! flignore )
            {
                short ctcharsinbuf = 3;
                BOOL flbreak = NO;

                if( flendtext )
                {
                    if( ! ixinbuf ) break;
                    if( ( ixinbuf == 1 ) || ( ixinbuf == 2 ) ) ctcharsinbuf = 1;
                    else ctcharsinbuf = 2;
                    ixinbuf = 3;
                    flbreak = YES;
                }

                inbuf [ixinbuf++] = ch;

                if( ixinbuf == 4 )
                {
                    ixinbuf = 0;
                    outbuf [0] = ( inbuf[0] << 2 ) | ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x30) >> 4 );
                    outbuf [1] = ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x0F ) << 4 ) | ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x3C ) >> 2 );
                    outbuf [2] = ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x03 ) << 6 ) | ( inbuf[3] & 0x3F );

                    for( i = 0; i < ctcharsinbuf; i++ )
                    [mutableData appendBytes:&outbuf[i] length:1];
                }

                if( flbreak )  break;
            }
        }
    }

    self = [self initWithData:mutableData];
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -

- (NSString *)base64Encoding
{
    return [self base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];
}

- (NSString *)base64EncodingWithLineLength:(NSUInteger)lineLength
{
    const unsigned char   *bytes = [self bytes];
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:self.length];
    unsigned long ixtext = 0;
    unsigned long lentext = self.length;
    long ctremaining = 0;
    unsigned char inbuf[3], outbuf[4];
    unsigned short i = 0;
    unsigned short charsonline = 0, ctcopy = 0;
    unsigned long ix = 0;

    while( YES )
    {
        ctremaining = lentext - ixtext;
        if( ctremaining <= 0 ) break;

        for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            ix = ixtext + i;
            if( ix < lentext ) inbuf[i] = bytes[ix];
            else inbuf [i] = 0;
        }

        outbuf [0] = (inbuf [0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
        outbuf [1] = ((inbuf [0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((inbuf [1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
        outbuf [2] = ((inbuf [1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((inbuf [2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
        outbuf [3] = inbuf [2] & 0x3F;
        ctcopy = 4;

        switch( ctremaining )
        {
            case 1:
            ctcopy = 2;
            break;
            case 2:
            ctcopy = 3;
            break;
        }

        for( i = 0; i < ctcopy; i++ )
        [result appendFormat:@"%c", encodingTable[outbuf[i]]];

        for( i = ctcopy; i < 4; i++ )
        [result appendString:@"="];

        ixtext += 3;
        charsonline += 4;

        if( lineLength > 0 )
        {
            if( charsonline >= lineLength )
            {
                charsonline = 0;
                [result appendString:@"\n"];
            }
        }
    }

    return [NSString stringWithString:result];
}
#pragma mark -
- (BOOL)hasPrefixBytes:(const void *)prefix length:(NSUInteger)length
{
    if( ! prefix || ! length || self.length < length ) return NO;
    return ( memcmp( [self bytes], prefix, length ) == 0 );
}

- (BOOL)hasSuffixBytes:(const void *)suffix length:(NSUInteger)length
{
    if( ! suffix || ! length || self.length < length ) return NO;
    return ( memcmp( ((const char *)[self bytes] + (self.length - length)), suffix, length ) == 0  );
}

@end
```

Comment: iOS7 includes Base64 encoding: `- (NSData *)base64EncodedDataWithOptions:(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)options` and `- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)options`

Answer (score 0):

Use a key that matches the algorithm key size, do not rely on padding being the same. If you want to use a string as the key run it through PBKDF2 to create a full length secure key.

Why use ASE256 with a short key?

How does node.js pad the data, PKCS7 or some other non-standard method like php uses.

If you are going to use CBC mode (a good idea) then use an explicit iv, do not assume each side will handle a NULL iv the same way.

Start simple, no padding, data exactly one block in length, key exactly the size of the algorithm, ECB mode. Get that to work, then add back in the other options one at a time.

Doing cryptography correctly is not easy or simple. A single mistake (bug) can render the entire security null. Get your design vetted (yes, pay a domain expert to do that) if you really want security as opposed to a good but failed try, that is what I do.

Comment: If there is a disagreement with the answer please specify what it is so others can be aware and a correction could be made.